# How to create iframe then append javascript to it with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I trying to create iframe then add script to it and script will run. Iframe created, but it always get errors in process of appending script to that iframe. Please help.

```
<div align="center" id="adframe1">
<script type="text/javascript">
var response1 = '<script>var ad_unit="123";</scr'+'ipt><script src="http://abc.com/abc.js"></scr'+'ipt>';
$('<iframe id="adframe1mopub"/>').appendTo('#adframe1');
$('#adframe1mopub').ready(function() {
$('#adframe1mopub').contents().find('body').append(response1);
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on "always get errors"? what errors?

Comment: What is the error?  Sounds like you are trying to do something that is not allowed for security reasons.  I believe you are prohibited from manipulating scripts on iframes for XSS concerns.

Comment: What is the point of putting javascript code inside the iframe rather than executing it directly?

Comment: the error about </script> .. you can test at http://www.xaluan.com/t.php

.the point of puting javascript in iframe cause it from adnetwork.. i using their code in the mobile web site version .. the JavaScript ( not async type ) block other element of the page until it loaded, i'm trying to get rid of it by load ads same time with content..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this script:

HTML:

```
​<div id=container-iframe>​</div>​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
var response1 = '<script>var ad_unit="123";</scr' + 'ipt><script src="http://abc.com/abc.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';

$('<iframe></iframe>', { id: 'adframe1mopub' }).bind('load', function(event) {

    if (!this.contentWindow) {
        return;
    }

    this.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML += response1;

}).appendTo('#container-iframe');
```

But it would be best way to implement this:

```
$('<iframe></iframe>', { id: 'myiframe' }).bind('load', function(event) {

    if (!this.contentWindow) {
        return;
    }

    var scripWidthCode = document.createElement('script');
    scripWidthCode.type ='text/javascript';
    scripWidthCode.innerText = 'var ad_unit="123";';

    this.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scripWidthCode);

    var scripWidthSrc = document.createElement('script');
    scripWidthSrc.type ='text/javascript';
    scripWidthSrc.src = 'http://abc.com/abc.js';

    this.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scripWidthSrc);

}).appendTo('#container-iframe');
```

​
[test](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/fwA3u/)